# Событие при наведении

Tags: условия, события, css, sass, compass

Есть изображение и блок с текстом, паталась сделать чтобы при наведении курсора на картинку появлялся текст, без js, на sass. If-else наверное... Кто поможет?:3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
div.image-wrap
-> img
-> div.text
```

---

```
div.image-wrap div.text
  display: none
div.image-wrap:hover div.text
  display: block
```

Comment: А блок текста и картинка обязательно должны содержаться в одном блоке?

Comment: @Ion Napoleon, да, наведение на элемент может влиять только на этот элемент и нижележащие. Возможно, в css3 есть какие-то новведения, которых я не видел, но это вряд ли будет кроссбраузерно. Вам так жалко этот лишний враппер?

Comment: нет, просто придется повозиться с выравниванием. спасибо